# US20050258178 is this patent vaild in the EU

Tags: international

In reference to the patent: [US20050258178](https://www.google.com/patents/US20050258178)

Is this patent still paid up and vaild? in The EU?

Comment: This is an application, not a patent.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to ask if a patent is valid in the EU, since European patent have nothing to do with the EU (though this will change with the unitary patent, whenever that happens).

Answer (score 2):

This patent is an application and has not been granted (google patents tells you as there is no date of grant and no granted patent associated with this application number (app. numbers start with a year, granted patents have a different format, but be careful, the application (numbers) don't disappear when the patent is granted) (check espacenet, public pair, ...)). It may or may not be granted in the future. If it does get granted, the protection applies backwards to the time where it was an application as far as the claims of the granted patent could be reasonably foreseen from the application.

This is a US patent application without an international or European application associated. (https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadocPatentFamily?CC=US&NR=2005258178A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20051124&DB=&locale=). Even if this patent gets granted, it will not cover Europe.

This does not mean however, that there cannot be other relevant applications or granted patents (both in the US and Europe) that would impede you from using this invention. It might for example be an improvement of a normal bowl plate and therefore fall under the scope of bowl plate patents (unlikely, but it's an example).

Further research is indicated.